# How add paroller in bootstrap 4 carousel

Tags: bootstrap-4, parallax

how to add parallax effect to bootstrap 4 carousel?

Parallax which I use is: https://tgomilar.github.io/paroller.js/

By adding the following code nothing happens:

```
<div class = "carousel-item" data-paroller-factor = "0.3">
    ...
</div>
```

Thanks for the hints!

Comment: try removing spaces.

Comment: Unfortunately, nothing helped

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve by putting a parallax effect into a carousel? A carousel already has movement. Adding another movement effect on top of that seems very wrong to me.